# C# script task in SSIS to concatane two SSIS variables, pass the result to Webclient class, and then write the output (JSON) to a third SSIS variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, variables, ssis, webclient

I am trying to take two SSIS variables, concatenate them, pass them to the Webclient class, and write the result to a third SSIS variable. This third variable is then written to the database.

When debugging the script, the concatenated string I create returns the proper output when I paste it into it into a web browser (it creates JSON), but it simply returns a generic error message when I run this as part of the SSIS package.

As you can probably tell, I am very new to writing C#, but I making a dedicated effort to learning it.

Any help from you guys would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have:

```
public void Main()
{
    var url = Dts.Variables["User::URL"].Value.ToString();
    var inputJSON = Dts.Variables["User::inputJSON"].Value.ToString();
    var fullurl = (url + inputJSON);


    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var json = webClient.DownloadString(fullurl);


        Dts.Variables["User::outputJSON"].Value = json;



        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

}

#region ScriptResults declaration
/// <summary>
/// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
/// result of the script.
/// 
/// This code was generated automatically.
/// </summary>
enum ScriptResults
{
    Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
    Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
};
#endregion

}
```

Comment: Add the error you get when using the WebClient through the script. Also put a breakpoint and debug the script so you know the problem is the WebClient or not.

Comment: Hello EzLo, I have been using breakpoints to diagnose the issue. When the string is parsed, and then passed Webclient, it is definitely the correct URL.

Sorry for the ambiguity regarding the error that i mentioned: there is no specifici error message returned from the package/script task. The error is return from the API - it's as if it doesn't recognize the string that has been passed to it. I am confused because if i use the exact same string within a web browser, the correct information is returned.

Comment: There might be a specific header, enconding, or another parameter you need to add to `webClient` before requesting the page. Post the error from the API, it will help solving the issue.

Comment: hi ezlo, thanks for helping me. The error is as follows:    {"error":{"code":"useragent_not_found","message":"Useragent Not Found"}}

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your web service validates the user agent from the request, try adding one like the following (simulating a Mozilla agent, for example). The user agent needs to be included in the header of the request.

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    var json = webClient.DownloadString(fullurl);
    Dts.Variables["User::outputJSON"].Value = json;
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

More info on user agents with `WebClient` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Comment: The API accepts an ambiguous string, and outputs the user agent details in tidy json. I'm using this service: http://useragentapi.com. Still have issues with it... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I will continue to try and find a solution to get this to work. If i find it, i will post a reply. Thanks

Comment: Hi, still can't seem to get this working, even when I include the header - it still returns the same error. I have debugged this the issue seems to be that the string that is being passed to the API is not being "processed" correctly. 

This is strange, because when I run this and output the "json" variable to the command line, everything works as it should. I am really at a loss